# Dynamic Date Parameter in Airflow DAG for Snowflake SQL Query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, parameter-passing, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using Google Cloud Composer with Airflow to run a SQL query on Snowflake. I need to set a date parameter based on a condition and then use that parameter in my SQL file. Specifically, I'm trying to determine the date based on whether the previous month is the end of a quarter. If so, I want to adjust my parameter accordingly, and reuse it in all the relevant places of the query

I have tried to set the parameter as part of a multi-statement SQL file to run in the DAG as so:

```sql
DECLARE
    VAR_QTR DATE;

BEGIN
    -- Set your VAR_QTR
    SET VAR_QTR = (
        SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE::DATE - INTERVAL '1 month') % 3 = 0 
            THEN DATE_TRUNC('quarter', CURRENT_DATE::DATE) - INTERVAL '1 quarter'
            ELSE DATE_TRUNC('quarter', CURRENT_DATE::DATE) - INTERVAL '0 quarter'
        END
    )
   ;

SOME SQL CODE HERE...
LEFT JOIN 
        TABLE dc
        ON dc.company_id = c.COMPANY_ID
        AND dc.deleted_at <= :$VAR_QTR 
END;
```

The error I'm getting in airflow is Session variable '$VAR_QTR' does not exist. How can I do this in Airflow with the SQL kept inside a fil (and not in the DAG itself)

Comment: If you want to have everything inside SQL file then it has nothing to do with any tool except the database itself. For the current code there's no need to `set` anything, just use an [assignment operator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#assigning-a-value-to-a-declared-variable): `var_qtr := <code>`. And then [use it](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding) as a bind variable: `select null from some_table where some_column = :var_qtr`

Comment: My code works just fine in my IDE, the problem is once it's hosted in Composer. It seems that the session variable gets lost

Comment: What Airflow Operator are you using?

Comment: Snowflake, but I welcome any solution to this problem. Even one outside of the scope of what I provided